# Making a nav bar even in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

so I'm trying to get my nav bar to basically, look nicer, I've designed it mostly how I want it in CSS, but each link is the size according to it's word size, so each block/link is sized differently (hope that makes sense) so I'm wanting to make them all the same size not/not dependent on word length. I'm also wanting to change the color behind the links (basically make it so the color stretches to the sides) I included a link to a picture explaining what I'm talking about: http://postimg.org/image/mdoq7vwy7/ . Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its a dead link you gave us and you did not provide any code , please update your answer so that we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: Link works fine here..

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith the link works fine

Comment: @DylanB even if the link works, there still is no code. If someone answers this question for him and in the future the link is no good, it creates an unclear question for others to view in the future.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I didn't say anything about the missing code, simply that you're wrong in saying the link is dead. I agree that the code should be posted as well

Comment: I cannot view the link, so its dead to me

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't include the picture in the thread, wouldn't let me, said I didn't have enough reputation points (I think that's what they were called)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use flexbox. Flexbox can make all the item the same size regardless of the content.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cameronjonesweb/afsxgm82/1/)

```
ul{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul li{
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-flex:1;
    -ms-flex:1;
    flex:1;
    text-align:center;
}
```

PS. It's hard to give you help without you providing any code

Comment: @DylanB flexbox is still the answer regardless of the code. Unless you want to use tables...

Comment: I don't disagree, but this implementation could be completely wrong

Comment: @DylanB Stop trolling!, the OP needs to add code! without it, it is a guessing game on what will work best.

Comment: @DylanB if you don't like my answer, answer it better yourself or flag my answer. It's simple enough

Comment: The question should be closed, no need for further discussion. it is unclear and difficult to answer correctly. @cameronjonesweb your solution will work.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Yes, the OP does need to add code. Which is why there's no point in answering the question yet, and that is all I said here.

Comment: So downvote the question, flag it and add a comment to the question, note the answer.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Thank you, once again for making assumptions that I haven't done that already. You've already commented stating the lack of code, I've already flagged the question and this answer, while probably correct, just wasted Cameron's time because there's no way of knowing how the OP went about implementing the nav

Comment: Guys, please, as far question concern, agree with @DylanB and as far answer concern, no doubt it's an excellent guess but even OP used this code `flex` doesn't support fully i.e 10 and below so still this is not proper solution just an excellent guess so again agree with @Dylan, SO is not for guessing but for proper solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To make each link in the navbar the same width, give them all the same class and do this css:

`.list-class { width: 100px; }`

And to make the color stretch past the margins, I would try this:

`li { padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px }`

Assuming you are using lists for your navbar.  It's a little hard to help without the code but hopefully this helped